# Get the next seven days of the week in views - Django

Tags: django

How to get seven consecutive days of the week in views using Django. I try this, but it returns an error.

```
from datetime import datetime

day = datetime.now()
day_1 = datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(days=1)
day_2 = datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(days=2)
day_3 = datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(days=3)
day_4 = datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(days=4)
day_5 = datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(days=5)
day_6 = datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(days=6)
day_7 = datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(days=7)
```

It returns:

```
type object 'datetime.datetime' has no attribute 'timedelta'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `datetime` in `datetime.timedelta` is about the module not the class, since you here import the class, you can also import `timedelta` directly:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

day = datetime.now()
day1 = day + timedelta(days=1)
day2 = day + timedelta(days=2)
day3 = day + timedelta(days=3)
day4 = day + timedelta(days=4)
day5 = day + timedelta(days=5)
day6 = day + timedelta(days=6)
day7 = day + timedelta(days=7)
```

Answer (score 2):

import `timedelta` from `datetime` and use directly as

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

day = datetime.now()
day_1 = datetime.now() + timedelta(days=1)
day_2 = datetime.now() + timedelta(days=2)
day_3 = datetime.now() + timedelta(days=3)
day_4 = datetime.now() + timedelta(days=4)
day_5 = datetime.now() + timedelta(days=5)
day_6 = datetime.now() + timedelta(days=6)
day_7 = datetime.now() + timedelta(days=7)
```